# How do I attached language specific css in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, theming

As the question states - how do I include a stylesheet based on a language? It has nothing to do with right to left reading, but for different colours etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the "[lang](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-css-lang)" attributes to style the language.

Here is the [example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_lang):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p:lang(it) { 
    background: yellow;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>I live in Italy.</p>
<p lang="it">Ciao bella!</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> For :lang to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared.</p>

</body>
</html>
```